# Puppet duplicate declaration error with conditional statement

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to configure global settings for the Puppet postgresql resource. I want to do it conditionally. I'm using an `if` statement to configure it depending on the contents of a variable.

```
define setup_postgresql_globals (
  $datadir,
) {
  if $datadir {
    class { 'postgresql::globals':
      datadir         => "${datadir}",
      needs_initdb    => true,
      version         => '9.3',
    }
  }
  else {
    class { 'postgresql::globals':
      needs_initdb    => true,
      version         => '9.3',
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error.

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Postgresql::Globals] is already declared
```

I only want to pass the `datadir` argument to `postgresql::globals` if it contains a value.

How can I use a conditional statement, and not get a duplicate declaration error?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use a conditional statement, and not get a duplicate declaration error?

The problem is not the conditional statement, but rather the fact that you declare more than one instance of `setup_postgresql_globals`.  The same class is declared each time, and although classes are idempotent and can be declared multiple times, only the first evaluation of a declaration of a given class can use the [resource-like syntax](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like).  All others must use one of the variations of include-like syntax.

In part for this reason, it is poor form to put a resource-like class declaration into a defined type.  Doing so is asking for trouble.  If you need to use a resource-like class declaration then put it in another class.  That possibly solves the problem altogether, but at worst pushes it up to a higher level.  It looks like this is probably a reasonable approach in your case, because a `setup_postgresql_globals` sure sounds like something that should itself be idempotent.

Consider also that classes -- but not defines -- can make use of automatic data binding.  Relying on external data to be automatically bound to your class parameters is often a good way to replace resource-like class declarations with include-like ones.  When applied in appropriate moderation, that can yield cleaner, simpler, easier to use and maintain manifests.

Answer (score 2):

> I only want to pass the datadir argument to postgresql::globals if it contains a value.

You should not worry about not passing `datadir` if it does not contain a value. Just pass the paramater to the `postgresql::globals` along with your other paramaters. If the `datadir` has a value the class will use it, and if it does not then `postgresql::globals` will handle it just fine and use its own defaults. You need to modify the way your passing the paramater though, this will not work: `datadir => "${datadir}"`, you must pass the it like this `datadir => $datadir,`. Your define could be as simple as this:

```
define setup_postgresql_globals (
  $datadir = undef,
) {
  class { 'postgresql::globals':
    datadir         => $datadir,
    needs_initdb    => true,
    version         => '9.3',
  }
}
```

The reason your getting `Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Postgresql::Globals] is already declared`, is becuase you are instantiating your define multipule times. By nature a define can be instantiated mutluple time so it can be problematic to do a class like include within one since you can only include a class like this once. There are a couple of ways you can resolve this issue.

1) Evaluate your need for this define at all. It seams like you created this define just to handle the `datadir` paramater being a `undef` value. As I have shown obove you might not need this define since your logic is not needed.

2) You should only do basic includes of classes within a define. You can include a class like this multuple times saftly. You would have to handle setting `datadir` via the automatic paramater lookup system from hiera. For example:

```
define setup_postgresql_globals (
  $datadir = undef,
) {
  include 'postgresql::globals'
}
```

Again you should probably remove this define and handle including `postgresql::globals` from where your instantiating `setup_postgresql_globals`.